# Height from keyboard to navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard, height

[image]

I need to create a tableview with the height from the keyboard y position to the navigation bar. The picture show a TableViewController where the textfields at the second section show the keyboard, I tried with the bounds and the scroll position but it doesn't work.

Anyone know how can I know this dimmensions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing UITableView bottom Constraint.

Pin your UITableView bottom to superView.Then register for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`/`UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and get from NSNotification object keyboard frame and change bottom constraint constant, like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    self.tableViewBottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardRect);
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```